# How to prevent writing on internal disk when external disk is not available

Tags: mount, hard-drive, disk

I have 2 disks -
128GB disk (internal) - /
2000GB disk (external) - /mnt/backup

How to prevent writing on 128GB disk if external disk is unavailable or unplugged?
Because archive app writing on /mnt/backup folder and does not care what disk it uses.

Ubuntu server 21.10

Comment: Which "archive app"? Ubuntu release/version?

Comment: Archive app is Timemachine. On Ubuntu is installed SMB